# "Missing number" error using `\pgfmathsetmacro` with the `ifthenelse` operator

Tags: pgfmath

I am trying to use logical functions in `pgfmath` and getting unexpected errors.  It seems to be related to the use of `\pgfmathsetmacro`, which according to my understanding should be equivalent to `\pgfmathparse{whatever}\let\macro=\pgfmathresult`.  However, the following example from the manual works with `\pgfmathparse` and gives the error

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
&lt;to be read again&gt; 
                   n
l.52 ...etmacro\macro{ifthenelse(5==4,"yes","no")}
                                                   \macro
```

when used with `\pgfmathsetmacro`:

```
\pgfmathparse         {ifthenelse(5==4,"yes","no")}% Works
\pgfmathsetmacro\macro{ifthenelse(5==4,"yes","no")}% Fails
```

Shouldn't I be able to do this?

Comment: After looking at the `\tracingall` output for not very long, I think it might be a bug: pgf is trying to set a `\dimen` register to "no", which is not going to work.

Comment: Note that this turns out to not being related to the ifthenelse operator (so the title can be misleading). `\pgfmathsetmacro\macro{"no"}` won't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the definition of `\pgfmathsetmacro` in file `pgfmathcalc.code.tex`.

```
\def\pgfmathsetmacro#1#2{%
  \begingroup%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfmath@x{#2}%
    \edef#1{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgfmath@x}}%
    \pgfmath@smuggleone{#1}%
  \endgroup%
}
```

The use of `\pgfmathsetlength` prevents from using something else than numbers as a result of the evaluation of `#2` by `\pgfmathparse` (which is the case in your sample code). As Bruno Le Floch pointed out in comment, this leads to assign `nopt` to the dimension `\pgfmath@x` which does not work.

I must admit it's not the behavior I would expect looking at the documentation. So at least, it should be specified in the doc or the macro should be modified to deal with such string cases.