# \pgfmathsetmacro - dimension too large (biggest value allowed?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, pgfplots, pgfmath

I want to import some data with parameters to parametrize some plots. After importing a table, I assign specific variables of the table to a placeholder by using `\pgfplotstablegetelem`. And it works fine. Until some values getting to big:

Apparently the command `\pgfmathsetmacro` doesn't like values bigger than `16383` - an error `dimension too large` appears. Is there a reason why? And is it possible to increase that threshold such that also numbers in the `50000`-range are excepted?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={test(\tmp) = x/\tmp;}]
        \begin{axis}[samples=100,domain=0:1]
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{16383}
            % \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{16384} % Error
            \addplot (x,{test(\tmp)});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've checked other `dimensions too large` postings here but haven't found a satisfying answer yet. Maybe you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Some other options → [calculations - How to calculate numbers bigger than 16383 in tikz? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662308/how-to-calculate-numbers-bigger-than-16383-in-tikz) & [tikz pgf - Calculation with Large numbers - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624566/calculation-with-large-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `fpu` library that ships with `TikZ` and that `pgfplots` uses internally. It allows calculations in the range from -1*10^324 to 1*10^324:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
\pgfmathparse{16383+1}
\edef\tmp{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={test(\tmp) = x/\tmp;}]
    \begin{axis}[samples=100,domain=0:1]
        \addplot (x,{test(\tmp)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18):

From the [pgf manual 2.10csv](http://altermundus.com/pages/builds/pgf_2.10-CVS.pdf) page 694:

> It should be noted that all calculations must not exceed ±16383.99999
>   at any point, because the underlying computations rely on TeX
>   dimensions. This means that many of the underlying computations are
>   necessarily approximate and that in addition, are not very fast. TeX
>   is, after all, a typesetting language and not ideally suited to
>   relatively advanced mathematical operations. However, it is possible
>   to change the computations as described in Section 76.

From the [*TeX Book*](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/tex) page 114:

> 16383.99998 pt (TeX’s largest dimen)

In [*Notes On Programming in TeX*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/latex/pgfplots/TeX-programming-notes.pdf) Chirstian Feuersänger pointed out

> The `\dimen` registers perform their arithmetic’s internally with 32 bit
>   scaled integers, so called ‘scaled point’ with unit `sp`. It holds
>   1 pt = 65536 sp = 2<sup>16</sup> sp. One of the 32 bits is used as sign. The total
>   number range in pt is [−(2<sup>30</sup> − 1)/2<sup>16</sup>, (2<sup>30</sup> − 1)/2<sup>16</sup> ] =
>   [−16383.9998, +16383.9998]<sup>1</sup>.
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup> Please note that this does not cover the complete range of a 32 bit integer, I do not know why</sub>

Comment: ok thanks. just for curiosity: where does the `±16383.99999` come from?
Changing the mathematical engine won't really solve my problems, so I better change the input data. But thanks anyway!

Comment: `pgf` uses TeX dimensions to do its mathematics. They are integers in units called 'scaled points', with a maximum of 2^32 - 1. The conversion to points comes out to the limit of ±16383.99999.

Answer (score 4):

I want to note my old question ["Missing number" error using `\pgfmathsetmacro` with the `ifthenelse` operator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43226/missing-number-error-using-pgfmathsetmacro-with-the-ifthenelse-operator), in which I observed another inconsistency in `\pgfmathsetmacro`.  Effectively, according to the accepted answer, this command can *only* set the macro in question to a TeX dimensions.  Thus, it is constrained by the limitations of TeX arithmetic in addition to the limitations of being numerical in the first place.  In particular, your code would work with the construct `\pgfmathparse{16384}\let\tmp\pgfmathresult` even though that value exceeds TeX's capabilities, because `pgfplots` uses the floating-point library and handles big numbers.

Comment: Good to know. I somehow solved my problem in a different way but who knows one I have to deal with big numbers again.

Comment: @Ryan Reich, could you help me on my question 

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422561/tikz-tree-too-large-many-nodes

I don't know how to use you one line solution in my case.

Comment: @user565739 I'm afraid I can't; I don't use TeX anymore and can't answer questions about it.