# Tweakes to invoice

Tags: formatting, koma-script

I need help fine tuning this document. I basically need three things:

1. Get rid of the duplicate company information on top of "Client"
2. Be able to stamp today's date automatically. I tried using
   "datetime" package but every time I run the script it collapses.
3. Calculate the tax automatically (can that be done in LaTeX?)

PS: the example comes with an external file called "template.lco" Inside that file I found the following:

```
\ProvidesFile{template.loc}[]

% firstfootvpos has to have more space to the bottom
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{\paperheight}
\@addtoplength[-]{firstfootvpos}{30mm}
```

And here's the code for the actual document:

```
\documentclass[DIN, pagenumber=false, parskip=half, 
fromalign=right, 
fromphone=true, 
fromfax=false,
fromrule=false]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{datetime}

\LoadLetterOption{template}
\newcommand{\stdlohn}[0]{18 \% }
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{Company}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49 (0) 123 / 1234 1234}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address}
\setkomavar{frombank}{Bank info}

\setkomavar{subject}[]{Service description}
\setkomavar{yourmail}[Code]{BAG-EB-00001}
\setkomavar{date}[Date]{06 July 2015}

\firstfoot{
\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\footnotesize 

\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Company:}}\\ 
Info \\
\end{tabular}
\hfill{}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Bank:}}\\ 
Bank name\\
\end{tabular}
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{
\textbf{Client}\\ 
Name\\
}

\opening{\ }
\vspace{-1.9cm}

\begin{longtable}{p{7.8cm}p{1.0cm}p{1cm}p{2.7cm}p{2.5cm}}
\hline  
Description & Amount & U & Price & Total\\
\hline 

\textbf{Service}\\
Service & 1 & H & USD 60.00 {} & USD 60.00{}\\ \\
\hline\hline 
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{p{5.5cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}}
\hline A & \stdlohn Tax & B\\
\hline 
USD 6,000.00{} & USD 6,000.00 & \textbf{USD 6,000.00}{}\\
\hline 
\hline  
\end{longtable}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I changed the code to a MWE.

With the two commands you can print the taxes only or the sum of both values. You can place them wherever you want them to appear.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfmath}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    precision=2,
    set thousands separator={.},
    set decimal separator={,}
    }

\newcommand{\taxes}[2]{%
    \pgfmathparse{#1*#2/100}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
    }

\newcommand{\addtaxes}[2]{%
    \pgfmathparse{#1+#1*#2/100}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
    }

\def\taxval{18}
\def\money{4.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cr}
Worktime & \pgfmathprintnumber{\money} \\
Taxes (\taxval\,\%)& \taxes{\money}{\taxval} \\
Sum & \addtaxes{\money}{\taxval}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I insert the script for "\pgfmathprintnumber" I receive the following error: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.22 \pgfkeys
             {/pgf/number format/.cd,
?

Comment: apart from that, how do I apply that command to my document. That means, how do I calculate the tax automatically and also the final price of the invoice (Tax = A*1.18; B = A + Tax). I hope this makes things more clear.

Comment: @killthepixelnow I changed my answer to an working example.

Comment: Awesome! It worked perfectly. Just out of curiosity, when I enter a four digit figure (e.g. 7000) I receive an error. Why is that?

Comment: I didn't get that error before. But it appears to be a problem in the default math engine. A solution is described here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54803/79099. Just add '\usepackage{pgfplots}' and '\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}' to your file and it should work.

Comment: Perfect! That solved the issue. One last thing, I tried formating my numbers like this: "1,000.00" by using: "set thousands separator={,},set decimal separator={.}" but I always get "1,000,00." Any idea how to change that?

Comment: I get the correct result when I change the separators.

Comment: Funny, when I use another character (for instance, an X) it appears as a separator (1,000X00. Only when I use a dot (".") it goes back to a comma (1,000,00). SOLVED: Modified the Babel package: "\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel} " at the beginning. Worked as a charm!

Answer (score 3):

I will only answer the first two questions.

If you do not want the back address on top of the "Client" use the class option

```
backaddress=false
```

To set the to set the todays stamp automatically in spanish remove `\usepackage{datetime}` and remove `\setkomavar{date}[Date]{06 July 2015}`.

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{template.lco}
\ProvidesFile{template.lco}[]

% firstfootvpos has to have more space to the bottom
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{\paperheight}
\@addtoplength[-]{firstfootvpos}{30mm}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[DIN, pagenumber=false, parskip=half, 
fromalign=right, 
fromphone=true, 
fromfax=false,
fromrule=false,
backaddress=false,
% numericaldate
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{eurosym}
%\usepackage{datetime}% <- removed

\LoadLetterOption{template}
\newcommand{\stdlohn}[0]{18 \% }
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{Company}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49 (0) 123 / 1234 1234}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address}
\setkomavar{frombank}{Bank info}

\setkomavar{subject}[]{Service description}
\setkomavar{yourmail}[Code]{BAG-EB-00001}
%\setkomavar{date}[Date]{06 July 2015}% <-removed

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{% <- changed
\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\footnotesize 

\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Company:}}\\ 
Info \\
\end{tabular}
\hfill{}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Bank:}}\\ 
Bank name\\
\end{tabular}
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{
\textbf{Client}\\ 
Name\\
}

\opening{\ }
\vspace{-1.9cm}
\begin{longtable}{p{7.8cm}p{1.0cm}p{1cm}p{2.7cm}p{2.5cm}}
\hline  
Description & Amount & U & Price & Total\\
\hline 

\textbf{Service}\\
Service & 1 & H & USD 60.00 {} & USD 60.00{}\\ \\
\hline\hline 
\end{longtable}
\begin{longtable}{p{5.5cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}}
\hline A & \stdlohn Tax & B\\
\hline 
USD 6,000.00{} & USD 6,000.00 & \textbf{USD 6,000.00}{}\\
\hline 
\hline  
\end{longtable}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Note that I have changed `\firstfoot{...}` to `\setkomavar{firstfoot}{...}`. That is the uptodate syntax.

---

If the language of your document is `english` you can change the babel option to `english`. Then use

```
\usepackage[english]{isodate}\cleanlookdateon
```

instead loading `datetime` and remove `\setkomavar{date}[Date]{06 July 2015}` to set the todays stamp automatically in the same format.

[image]

Comment: backaddress command worked fine! Concerning the date, I want it to be in Spanish, but I tried the script in English like you suggested and I can't export the document.

Comment: I have changed my answer. Note that you have to remove package `datetime`.

Comment: Great, that worked perfectly!