# pgf-pie : Dimension too large

Tags: errors, pgfmath, pgf-pie

I used the package [pgf-pie](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-pie) to generate pie chart. The option `sum=auto` compute automatically the sum of all value. The following MWE give `Dimension too large` because [this reason](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54703/125774).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pie[sum=auto]{16384/foo}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I naively tried to [use fpu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54803/125774) in the following snippet of `pgf-pie.sty` :

```
% handle sum
\ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfpie@sum}{auto}}
{
  % sum all input
  \xdef\pgfpie@sum{0}
  \foreach \p/\t in {#2}
  {
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfpie@sum + \p}
    \xdef\pgfpie@sum{\pgfmathresult}
  }
}
{}
```

but adding `\RequirePackage{pgfplots}` give me more errors.

How to adjust correctly `pgf-pie.sty` so that it can support larger value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to enter large numbers directly. The `fpu` library can't be used for two reasons. First, the number format is incompatible with `\ifnum` (internally used by `pgf-pie`), because even with `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}` something like `\pgfmathparse{int(...)}` will give a result with a decimal point (e.g. `0.0`). And second, `pgf` internally assigns given lengths to dimen registers, which will lead to `dimension too large` errors for big numbers.

But it is possible to scale the numbers, using the `fpu` library, a new key (`scale numbers`), a little macro (`\pgfpie@scalenumber`) and some patching. With this, you still have to enter small numbers (their sum must not exceed 16383), but you can give a scaling factor, so the pie chart contains big numbers. Additionally, you have to set the precision to control decimal places. I used `\pgfmathprintnumber` here to get better formatting for the numbers, which also makes it possible, to get scientific notation, if you want.

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\makeatletter
% new key
\pgfkeys{/scale numbers/.store in=\pgfpie@scale,
         /scale numbers=1}
% macro for scaling
\newcommand*{\pgfpie@scalenumber}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}% enable fpu only locally
    \pgfmathparse{#1*\pgfpie@scale}%
    %\pgfmathroundtozerofill{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
    \endgroup
}
% patching the internal commands
\patchcmd{\pgfpie@slice}{\beforenumber#3}{\beforenumber\pgfpie@scalenumber{#3}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\pgfpie@slice}{\beforenumber#3}{\beforenumber\pgfpie@scalenumber{#3}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\pgfpie@square}{\beforenumber#3}{\beforenumber\pgfpie@scalenumber{#3}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\pgfpie@square}{\beforenumber#3}{\beforenumber\pgfpie@scalenumber{#3}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\pgfpie@cloud}{\beforenumber#3}{\beforenumber\pgfpie@scalenumber{#3}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\pgfpie@cloud}{\beforenumber#3}{\beforenumber\pgfpie@scalenumber{#3}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % set up number formatting
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
  fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=0,
  set thousands separator={\,}}

  \pie[sum=auto,scale numbers=1000]{1234.567/foo,1234.567/bar,1234.567/baz}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution! What is the limit of `scale numbers`? For instance, `\pie[sum=auto,scale numbers=100000000000]{0.92384797234000005/foo}` give me `92384796000` while `92384797234` is expected.

Comment: The `fpu` library can handle numbers up to 10^324, but it can only handle about 7 - 8 digits and the last one may show rounding errors. Thus, the value for `scale numbers` can be much higher, but you would only get more `0`s at the end (e.g. a value of `100000000000000` would result in `92384796000000`). Personally, with numbers that big, I would use scientific notation, because IMO it's easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

It can handle larger values than `pgfmath` because it uses `\fp_eval:n` from `l3fp` internally for the values of the slices.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  counterclockwise,
  pie,
  slices style={\WCvarB,draw=black},
  start angle=0,
  wheel data=\num{\WCvarA}
]{%
  1234567/blue!60/foo,
  1234567/cyan!60/bar,
  1234567/yellow!60/baz%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```