# Dimension too large in 3D geometry in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, dimensions, tikz-3d

I am facing a compilation error in a weird way. I have trimmed my code to the maximum but still my MWE is not too small, so I'll focus first on the weird part :

```
    \foreach \j in {0,1,...,5}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\AngleEntree}{-10*\j}

        \coordinate (centreCardan) at (-20,{-18*\j},5);

        % Circle 
        \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords]
        \draw[red,ultra thick,dashed] (centreCardan) circle (\r);
        \end{scope}

        %Tube
        \coordinate (centrePivVR) at ($(centreCardan)+ ({-5*cos(\AngleEntree)},{-5*sin(\AngleEntree)},0)$);
        %%
        \Pivot{(centrePivVR)}{blue, ultra thick}{ }{cos(\AngleEntree)}{sin(\AngleEntree)}{0}

    }
```

You can see the loop where it happens, `(centreCardan)` is a point used to place a figure, and I define it in each loop to offset every new figure under the previous one.

You can see the iterator is `\j`, and I multiply if by 18 to get the Y coordinate for `(centreCardan)` . If I stop `\j` at 4, it compiles, but with 5 it doesn't.

Up to this point nothing too surprising, but it gets weird if you use 10 instead of 18 as a multiplicator, then you can go up to 21 with `\j` ( 21 * 10  =210 > 5*18 = 90 ) so I don't quite understand what's happening.

If I remove the `\Pivot` line `\j` can go up to 38 with a 18 multiplicator

If you are able to dive in a 130 lines code, here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,esvect,tikz-3dplot} 

% Créer des canvas personnalisés pour toutes les orientations
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is plane}[]{\@setOxy#1}
\def\@setOxy O(#1,#2,#3)x(#4,#5,#6)y(#7,#8,#9)%
  {\def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
   \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
   \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{#7}{#8}{#9}}%
   \tikz@canvas@is@plane
  }
\makeatother  

%%%%% Environnement scope dans un canvas personnalisé avec normalisation du vecteur directeur
\newenvironment{NouveauPlan}[3]
{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\DoublCondi}{0}
    \ifdim\VaxecY pt=0 pt
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\DoublCondi}{\DoublCondi+1}
    \fi
    \ifdim\VaxecZ pt=0 pt
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\DoublCondi}{\DoublCondi+1}
    \fi
    \ifdim\DoublCondi pt=2 pt
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\XcordY}{1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\XcordZ}{0}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\YcordX}{0}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\YcordY}{0}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\YcordZ}{1}
    \else
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\NormX}{sqrt((#3)*(#3)+(#2)*(#2))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\NormY}{sqrt( ((#2)*(#2)+(#3)*(#3))*((#2)*(#2)+(#3)*(#3)) +  (#1)*(#2)*(#1)*(#2)  +  (#1)*(#3)*(#1)*(#3)  )}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\XcordY}{#3/\NormX}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\XcordZ}{(-1)*(#2)/\NormX}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\YcordX}{(-1)*((#2)*(#2)+(#3)*(#3))/\NormY}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\YcordY}{(#1)*(#2)/\NormY}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\YcordZ}{(#1)*(#3)/\NormY}
    \fi
%%%%%%%
\begin{scope}[canvas is plane={O(0,0,0)x(0,\XcordY,\XcordZ)y(\YcordX,\YcordY,\YcordZ)}]
}{\end{scope}}


%% Fonctions de Calcul %%

\newcommand*{\NormerVect}[3]{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\NormV}{sqrt((#1)*(#1)+(#2)*(#2)+(#3)*(#3))}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\VncX}{#1/\NormV}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\VncY}{#2/\NormV}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\VncZ}{#3/\NormV}
}

\newcommand*{\MultipliVect}[4]{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\VmcX}{#1*(#4)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\VmcY}{#2*(#4)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\VmcZ}{#3*(#4)}
}

\newcommand*{\CalculAxe}[3]{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\NormV}{sqrt((#1)*(#1)+(#2)*(#2)+(#3)*(#3))}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\VaxecX}{#1/\NormV}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\VaxecY}{#2/\NormV}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\VaxecZ}{#3/\NormV}
% Vecteur unitaire de l'axe
\coordinate (AxeUni) at (\VaxecX,\VaxecY,\VaxecZ);
\MultipliVect{\VaxecX}{\VaxecY}{\VaxecZ}{\l/2}
\coordinate (AxeMoitie) at(\VmcX,\VmcY,\VmcZ);

}

%% Liaisons Pivot %%

\newcommand*{\Pivot}[6]{
\CalculAxe{#4}{#5}{#6}

\coordinate (centre) at #1;
\coordinate (centrezp) at ($(centre)+(AxeMoitie)$) ;
\coordinate (centrezm) at ($(centre)-(AxeMoitie)$) ;

\begin{NouveauPlan}{#4}{#5}{#6}
\draw let \p1=($(centrezp)-(centrezm)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in  ($(centrezp)+(\n1-90:\r)$)
arc[radius=\r,start angle=\n1+270,delta angle=-540];
\end{NouveauPlan}

}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
[x={(0.710cm,-0.410cm)},y={(0cm,0.820cm)},z={(-0.710cm,-0.410cm)}]

% Vecteur Point de Vue
\pgfmathsetmacro{\VpvX}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\VpvY}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\VpvZ}{1}

% Dimensions
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}     % Rayon du cylindre 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\l}{4}     % Longueur cylindre

\foreach \j in {0,1,...,38}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\AngleEntree}{-10*\j}

    \coordinate (centreCardan) at (-20,{-18*\j},5);

    % Circle 
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords]
    \draw[red,ultra thick,dashed] (centreCardan) circle (\r);
    \end{scope}

    %Tube
    \coordinate (centrePivVR) at ($(centreCardan)+ ({-5*cos(\AngleEntree)},{-5*sin(\AngleEntree)},0)$);
    %%
    \Pivot{(centrePivVR)}{blue, ultra thick}{ }{cos(\AngleEntree)}{sin(\AngleEntree)}{0}

}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you to the braves who will give me some time.

Comment: At first sight it looks like the commont error about dimension too large when your draw pictures with large (about multiple meters) dimensions. Your code gives a 563.29cm height. What do you inted to do with this code ?

Comment: I intend to draw a mechanism with different positions and I offset each one 18cm lower, so drawing 5 should hardly go over 100cm, shouldn't it ?

Comment: Sometimes `tikz` uses invisible coordinates to construct paths which enlarge the actual bounding box, e.g. B-spline control points, so it is possible this is what is happenning here though it is difficult to be sure.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you compile your MWE with the 18 multiplicator and `\j` up to 38 ? Because on my system it compiles fine

Comment: Yes, sorry I had forgotten to uncomment my line \Pivot, which is the problematic one.

Comment: OK, I tried to compile your example, after some test it appears the last `centrePivVR` is at y-position `-15689pt` which is pretty close to the internal computational limit of TeX and therefore Ti*k*Z. So I guess any computation based on this coordinate (especially involving square roots and others will overflow this limit). Have a look at this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54702/141947 for possible alternatives

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to figure out what your code is supposed to do.  I understood it somehow, but not completely.  The computations in the preamble are not really illuminating.

This being said, I managed to move your sum limit up to *20* which is still too far from the *36* (I imagine for a full circle) you are looking for.  The price was to diminish the constant *-18* in `\coordinate (centreCardan) at (-20, {-18*\j}, 5);` to *-7*.  By the way, why do you need *-20* for the *x* coordinate?   You could put *0* instead without changing the output.

This brings me to two remarks and an interrogation.

1. I don't understand why *20* works and *21* doesn't in

```
  \foreach \j in {0, 1, ..., 20}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\AngleEntree}{-10*\j}    
    \coordinate (centreCardan) at (0, {-7*\j}, 5);
```

The *dimension too large* error is not given by what you actually draw (see below where I tried to estimate the maximal distance needed for the last drawn elements), but by the computations in `\Pivot`.  As you can see, the drawn elements involve dimensions of about *4000 pt* way
below the maximal *~16,370*.

[image]

2. If we draw everything without moving the point `(centreCardan)` we obtain something like this.

[image]

(I see the "circles" of a spring crushed on a plane which is rolled into a cylinder.)

3. So, what do you want in the end?  I don't think that you want a pdf file long like an Egyptian scroll.  I don't see the usefulness of it, but who knows.  If the final outcome you want is some sort of animation, then you should create
   separate images, i.e. **move the loop outside the `tikzpicture` environment**.  The *dimension too large* error will disappear.