# pgfmath gives me a wrong computation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

I am trying to do some plots with spherical coordinates and have a problem when computing some numbers in PGFPLOTS.

I add a MWE here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}


\begin{document}

 % compute angles
    \pgfmathsetmacro\a{-pi/5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\b{pi/10}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\phil{\a-\b}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\phih{\a+\b}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\thetal{\a-\b}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\thetah{\a+\b}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\s{cos(\thetal)*sin(\phil)}
    % this should be about -0.476
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\s}


\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image: wrong computation]

I should get $-0.4755282581475768$

Answer (score 4):

`sin` and `cos` want their argument in degree. Though they can be given in radians as well by appending `r` (manual, section 94.3.4).

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}


\begin{document}

 % compute angles
 %   \pgfmathsetmacro\a{-180/5}
 %   \pgfmathsetmacro\b{180/10}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\a{-pi/5 r}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\b{pi/10 r}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\phil{\a-\b}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\phih{\a+\b}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\thetal{\a-\b}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\thetah{\a+\b}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\s{cos(\thetal)*sin(\phil)}
    % this should be about -0.476
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\s}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is  there a way to tell PFGPLOTS that the unit for angle is radians? I ask becuause I had this set up in my script and it ignored it for computations:       trig format plots=rad,

Comment: @HermanJaramillo Yes, see  edit.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo While experimental (see page 1037-38 in the TikZ manual), you can try `\pgfkeys{/pgf/trig format=rad}`.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I would rather go with [xfp package](https://ctan.org/pkg/xfp?lang=en) to do the calculations for me due to its wide list of functions and the ability to handle big numbers operations without [such limitations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54702/2288).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfp,siunitx}


\begin{document}
 % compute angles
    \edef\a{-pi/5}
    \edef\b{pi/10}
    \edef\phil{\a-\b}
    \edef\phih{\a+\b}
    \edef\thetal{\a-\b}
    \edef\thetah{\a+\b}

    \edef\s{\fpeval{cos(\thetal)*sin(\phil)}}
    % this should be about -0.476
    \num{\s}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A dirty and overcomplicated trick

```
% xop.tex
%   run 
% pdflatex xop.tex
% asy xop-*.asy
% pdflatex xop.tex

\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\gdef\setasy#1{\gdef\s{#1}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\s{0}
\begin{asy}
  // compute angles
  real a=-pi/5;
  real b=pi/10;
  real phil=a-b;
  real phih=a+b;
  real thetal=a-b;
  real thetah=a+b;
  real s=cos(thetal)*sin(phil);
  tex("\setasy{"+string(s)+"}");
\end{asy}

\pgfmathprintnumber{\s} (\s)

\end{document}
```

[image]