# How to use declared TikZ functions in \foreach condition?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

How is it possible to use a `declare function` in the condition of `\foreach`? Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a = 0; b = 5;}]
  \foreach \x in {{a},...,{b}}{
    \draw (\x,0) -- (0,\x);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives me

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
```

(line 10, the closing bracket of the loop).

One can even use declared functions in the `[options list]` of `tikzpicture` in options coming behind `declare function`, but why not simply in `\foreach`?

Comment: I guess you can’t use it in foreach, because it doesn’t evaluate math at all, `sin(2)` doesn’t work either, does it?

Comment: As already pointed out by comments and answers, you need to evaluate the values first. Although it is possible to say to evaluate an expression inside the loop using `\foreach \x[evaluate=\x] in {…}` the loop still uses the un-evaluated values, in this case the loop goes still from `a` to `b` and not from `0` to `5`. `{a, ..., e}` would loop over `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` which could be some constants that get evaluated. You can't use it to loop over their values, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can evaluate the expression first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=0;b = 5;}]
\pgfmathparse{{a}}\let\pgfmathresulta\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{{b}}\let\pgfmathresultb\pgfmathresult
  \foreach \x in {\pgfmathresulta,...,\pgfmathresultb}{
    \draw (\x,0) -- (0,\x);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, my question was not detailed enough. I edited it. I actually need two functions in the range. But `\pgfmathresult` is only one container.

Comment: In this case you could use `\pgfmathsetmacro{<macro>}{<math expression>}` and then use `<macro>` …

Comment: @FooBar you could just use two macros one for each. I'll update to match

Comment: @FooBar see update (I kept to the spirit of the original rather that Tobi's version)

Comment: @Tobi: `\pgfmathsetmacro` is [dangerous](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43226/575) and doesn't do what it claims to do.  It seems never to be worth using over `\pgfmathparse` + `\let`.

Comment: @RyanReich: I didn’t know that. Thanks :-)

Comment: @RyanReich phew that was lucky as `\pgfmathparse` is the only pgf/tikz command I know about:-)

Comment: @David: pgfmath is very handy for printing text, too!  `\pgfmathparse{"Hello, world!"}\pgfmathresult`.

Answer (score 1):

This small code adds two keys to the optional `\foreach` use:

- `use int` and
- `use float`

I let the example speak for themselves:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a = 0; b = 5;}]
  \foreach \x[use int=a to b] \draw (\x,0) -- (0,\x);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x[use int=2 to 10 step 2] {
        \ifnum\x=\foreachEnd
            \tikzset{every path/.append style=thick}
        \fi
        \draw (\x/2,0) -- (0,\x/3);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Disclaimer: No warranties; probably breaks the very next moment.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifqrr@pgf@foreach@no@list
\pgfkeys{
    /pgf/foreach/.cd,
    @use/.code args={#1to#2}{%
        \qrr@pgf@foreach@no@listtrue
        \qrr@pgf@foreach@no@list@use\foreachStart{#1}%
        \pgfutil@in@{step}{#2}
        \ifpgfutil@in@
            \qrr@pgf@foreach@no@list@parse@step#2\pgffor@stop
        \else
            \qrr@pgf@foreach@no@list@parse@step#2step1\pgffor@stop
        \fi
        \edef\qrr@pgf@foreach@no@list@list{\foreachStart,\foreachSecond,...,\foreachEnd}},
    use int/.code={%
        \let\qrr@pgf@foreach@no@list@use\pgfmathtruncatemacro
        \pgfkeysalso{/pgf/foreach/@use={#1}}%
    },
    use float/.code={%
        \let\qrr@pgf@foreach@no@list@use\pgfmathsetmacro
        \pgfkeysalso{/pgf/foreach/@use={#1}}%
    }
}
\def\qrr@pgf@foreach@no@list@parse@step#1step#2\pgffor@stop{%
    \qrr@pgf@foreach@no@list@use\foreachEnd{#1}%
    \qrr@pgf@foreach@no@list@use\foreachSecond{\foreachStart+#2}%
}
\def\pgffor@vars{% manually extended, better etoolbox
    \pgfutil@ifnextchar i{\pgffor@@vars@end}{%
        \pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\pgffor@@vars@opt}{%]
            \pgfutil@ifnextchar/{\pgffor@@vars@slash@gobble}{%
                \ifqrr@pgf@foreach@no@list\expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo\else
                    \expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo\fi
                {\qrr@pgf@foreach@no@listfalse\pgffor@macro@list\qrr@pgf@foreach@no@list@list}
                {\pgffor@@vars}}}}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a = 0; b = 5;}]
  \foreach \x[use int=a to b] \draw (\x,0) -- (0,\x);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x[use int=2 to 10 step 2] {
        \ifnum\x=\foreachEnd
            \tikzset{every path/.append style=thick}
        \fi
        \draw (\x/2,0) -- (0,\x/3);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: `use int` and `use float` are part of the `ext.misc` library of my [`tikz-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext) package, they are explained in the [manual in section 15.3](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-ext/doc/tikz-ext-manual.pdf#subsection.15.3)