# A rather difficult ring like picture to be drawn

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, pgfplots, diagrams, pstricks

I desire a figure similar to the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,transform shape]
\draw (1,0) arc (0:90:1);
\draw (-1,0) arc (180:270:1);
\draw[fill=gray!30] (-1,0) -- (-2,0) arc (180:90:2) -- (0,1) arc (90:180:1);
\draw[fill=gray!30] (1,0) -- (2,0) arc (0:-90:2) -- (0,-1) arc (-90:0:1);
\node at (0.2,0.75) {\tiny $\phi^2$};
\node[rotate=50] at (-0.7,0.5) {\tiny $t=0$};
\node[rotate=50] at (0.7,-0.5) {\tiny $t=0$};
\node[rotate=50] at (-1.45,1.2) {\tiny $t=1$};
\node[rotate=50] at (1.45,-1.2) {\tiny $t=1$};
\node[rotate=50] at (-1.6,1.4) {\tiny $\partial \varphi (1)$};
\node[rotate=50] at (1.6,-1.4) {\tiny $\partial \varphi (1)$};
\node at (-2,2) {\tiny $\Omega_1$};
\node at (2,-2) {\tiny $\Omega_2$};
\node at (-1,1) {\tiny $\Delta \mathfrak{M}^2$};
\node at (1,-1) {\tiny $\Delta \mathfrak{M}^2$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

as developed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144166/how-to-draw-a-ring-like-diagram-with-some-labels-on-its-arcs).

However, the figure I desire this time around should be something like the following:

Consider a circle of radius 1. Divide the circle into 60 symmetric arcs. For each arc, starting with the 0-6 degree arc, increase the radius by `$.05n$` for n between 1 and 60. so the 354-360 arc should have a radius of `.05(60) + 1 =4`. Just as in the previous figure, each change in area should be shaded.   Here is a sketch of a similar looking object split into 12 arcs:

[image]

You can see that each arc has a radius larger than the previous, with the sqwiggles indicating shading and labels `$\{ \Omega \}_{i=1}^{n}$`, `$\phi^2$` and `$\partial \varphi$`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apparently it wasn't so difficult, regarding to the fast answers :)

(I'm always amazed how fast and comprehensive the answers here are.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This answer shows two to three approaches:

The **first** one shows a version where a few often used values are evaluated beforehand and are saved in a macro. Also, the `\startAngle` and the `\endRadius` are initialized as the `\foreach` loop only adds `\deltaAngle` for the angle and `.05` for the radius.

The `\foreach` loop is then used to iterate over the segments but their number (`\iN`) is not even used. The nodes
 are then places using simple math.

The **second** solution uses my TikZ library [`qrr.misc`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibraryqrr.misc.code.tex) which contains a few “fixes” and addition to PGF.

The used additions are the [`use int` key](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110996/16595) for `\foreach` that allows us to use arbitrary PGFmath for the `\foreach` loop and the `full arc` key as well as the `R` prefix from PGFmath. The `full arc` key is similar to the `\degrees[<n>]` macro from PSTricks. Instead of calculating the angle for the `<i>`th element of `<n>` elements (like with the `arcAngle` function of the third solution) it allows us to specify `<i> R` in a PGFmath-aware environment. I also added an alternative output. These solutions are probably slower than the first solution because they use more PGfmath and re-evaluate certain values repeatedly (but of course we could use them in `\foreach`’s `evaluate` key, too).

The **third** solution shows an only-PGmath solution that also implements the `full arc` key via the `arcAngle` function.

### Code 1

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={bigR(\n)=\smallR+.05*\n;}]
\newcommand*\smallR{1}
\newcommand*\segments{60}
\pgfmathsetmacro\deltaAngle{360/\segments}
\newcommand*\startAngle{-\deltaAngle}
\newcommand*\endRadius{\smallR}

\foreach \iN[evaluate={
  \startAngle=\startAngle+\deltaAngle;
  \endRadius=\endRadius+.05;},% or bigR \iN
  remember=\endRadius,
  remember=\startAngle] in {1,...,\segments}
  \filldraw[fill=gray!50] (\startAngle:\endRadius)
    arc [radius=\endRadius, start angle=\startAngle, delta angle=\deltaAngle]
                       -- (\startAngle+\deltaAngle:\smallR)
    arc [radius=\smallR, end angle=\startAngle, delta angle=-\deltaAngle] -- cycle;

\node                                                                   {$\phi^2$};
\node at (north west:{sqrt 2 * bigR(\segments/2)})                   {$\{\Omega\}_{i=1}^n$};
\node[rotate=-\deltaAngle/2, right] at (-\deltaAngle/2:bigR \segments) {$\partial \varphi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output 1

[image]

### Code 2

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{qrr.misc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={smallR=1; bigR(\n)=smallR+.05*\n; segments=20;},
  full arc=segments]% same as \degrees[segments] in PSTricks
\foreach \iN[evaluate={\endRadius=bigR(\iN+1);}, use int=0 to segments-1]
  \filldraw[fill=gray!50] (\iN R:\endRadius)
    arc [radius=\endRadius, start angle=+\iN R, delta angle=+1R]
                       -- (\iN R+1R:smallR)
    arc [radius=smallR, end angle=\iN R, delta angle=-1R] -- cycle;

\node                                              {$\phi^2$};
\node at (north west:{sqrt 2 * bigR(segments/2)})  {$\{\Omega\}_{i=1}^n$};
\node[rotate=-.5R, right] at (-.5R: bigR segments) {$\partial \varphi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={smallR=1; bigR(\n)=smallR+.05*\n; segments=20;},
  full arc=segments]
\filldraw[fill=gray!50] (right:smallR)
  \foreach \iN[evaluate={\endRadius=bigR(\iN+1);}, use int=0 to segments-1] {
    -- (\iN R:\endRadius) arc[radius=\endRadius, start angle=\iN R, delta angle=1R]}
    -- (right:smallR)     arc[radius=smallR, start angle=0, delta angle=-360];

\node                                              {$\phi^2$};
\node at (north west:{sqrt 2 * bigR(segments/2)})  {$\{\Omega\}_{i=1}^n$};
\node[rotate=-.5R, right] at (-.5R: bigR segments) {$\partial \varphi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output 2

[image][image]

### Code 3

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \segments in {1,...,60}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={smallR=1; bigR(\n)=smallR+.05*\n; segments=\segments;
                                      arcAngle(\i,\n)=360/\n*\i;}]
\useasboundingbox (-bigR 45,-bigR 50) rectangle (bigR 60,bigR 45) ++ (right:1.7em);
\foreach \iN[evaluate={
  \startAngle=arcAngle(\iN-1, segments);
  \endAngle=arcAngle(\iN, segments);
  \endRadius=bigR(\iN);}] in {1, ..., \segments}
  \filldraw[fill=gray!50] (\startAngle:\endRadius)
    arc [radius=\endRadius, start angle=\startAngle, end angle=\endAngle]
                       -- (\endAngle:smallR)
    arc [radius=smallR, start angle=\endAngle, end angle=\startAngle] -- cycle;
\node {$\phi^2$};
\node at (-{bigR(segments/2)}, {bigR(segments/2)}) {$\{\Omega\}_{i=1}^n$};
\node at ({bigR(segments/2)}, {bigR(segments/2)}) {$n = \segments$};
\node at ({-arcAngle(1, segments)/2}: {bigR(segments)})
  [rotate={-arcAngle(1, segments)/2}, right] {$\partial \varphi$};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

### Output 3

[image]

Comment: The code ca be written more efficicently, so that PGFmath doesn’t need to evaluate everything again … Is there interest [in this kind of outcome](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcwh7.png)?

Comment: This is the only answer so far that actually does not start with a rectangle of zero height, as the question asks.

Comment: I must have this GIF!

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I hope you're seriously considering to upload on CTAN your libraries.

Answer (score 18):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\def\N{60}
\def\R#1#2{1 3 #1 div #2 mul add}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-3.5)(4,2)
    \degrees[\N]
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=\numexpr\N+1]{0}{\N}{\R{\N}{t} t \pst@angleunit PtoC}{A}
    \multido{\ia=0+1,\ib=1+1}{\N}{\pscustom{\psarc(0,0){!\R{\N}{\ia}}{(A\ia)}{(A\ib)}\psarcn(0,0){1}{(A\ib)}{(A\ia)}\closepath}}
\end{pspicture}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Animated version

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\def\R#1#2{1 3 #1 div #2 mul add}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\multido{\i=1+1}{61}{%
\def\N{\i}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-3.5)(4,2)
    \degrees[\N]
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=\numexpr\N+1]{0}{\N}{\R{\N}{t} t \pst@angleunit PtoC}{A}
    \multido{\ia=0+1,\ib=1+1}{\N}{\pscustom{\psarc(0,0){!\R{\N}{\ia}}{(A\ia)}{(A\ib)}\psarcn(0,0){1}{(A\ib)}{(A\ia)}\closepath}}
\end{pspicture}}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do you compile this?

Comment: @Jake: As usual with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`.

Comment: Labeling is not my interest so it is ignored here.

Comment: @Jake Also works with `xelatex`.

Answer (score 17):

Is this something like what you want? Using `\foreach`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  \foreach \start in {0, 6, 12, ..., 354}
    \draw (\start:1+\start/300) arc (\start:\start+6:1+\start/300);
  \foreach \start in {0, 6, 12, ..., 354}
    \draw[fill=black!20] (\start:1) -- (\start:1+\start/300) -- (\start+6:1+\start/300) -- (\start+6:1)--cycle;
\draw (357:2.5) node {$\partial \varphi$};
\draw (345:0.5) node {$\varphi^2$};
\draw (150:2) node {$\{ \Omega \}_{i=1}^n$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very similar, with the exception of the labels.

Comment: no sir, only the last arc.

Comment: Ah, I understand!

Answer (score 16):

The requirements seem quite specific, so making it customizable seems less of an issue:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz{
\foreach \a in {0,6,...,354}
  \draw [fill=gray!50] 
    (\a:1) arc (\a:\a+6:1) -- (\a+6:1.05+\a/120) arc (\a+6:\a:1.05+\a/120) -- cycle;
\node {$\phi^2$};
\node at (-3,3) {$\{ \Omega \}_{i=1}^{n}$};
\node [anchor=171] at (357:1.05+357/120) {$\partial \varphi$};
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if some customization was required the following still works:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz{
\def\n{60}
\def\r{1}
\def\f{0.05}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\s=360/\n; \a=\s*\i;}]in {1,2,...,\n}
  \draw [fill=gray!50] 
    (\a:\r) arc (\a:\a-\s:\r) -- (\a-\s:\r+\f*\i) arc (\a-\s:\a:\r+\f*\i) -- cycle;
\node {$\phi^2$};
\node at (135:sqrt 2*1.5*\r+\f*\n/sqrt 2) {$\{ \Omega \}_{i=1}^{n}$};
\node [anchor=180-180/\n] at (-180/\n:\r+\f*\n) {$\partial \varphi$};
}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as before (Ok, the `\Omega` node is `0.00012pt` nearer the origin).

Or  with a bit of help from `gimp`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\def\m{100}
\def\r{1}
\def\f{0.05}
\begin{document}
\foreach\n in {5,...,\m}{
\tikz{
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=360/\n; \a=\s*\i;}]in {1,2,...,\n}
      \draw [fill=gray!50] 
        (\a:\r) arc (\a:\a-\s:\r) -- (\a-\s:\r+\f*\i) arc (\a-\s:\a:\r+\f*\i) -- cycle;
    \node {$\phi^2$};
    \node at (135:sqrt 2*\r+sqrt 2*\m*3/8*\f) {$\{ \Omega \}_{i=1}^{\n}$};
    \node [anchor=180-180/\n] at (-180/\n:\r+\f*\n) {$\partial \varphi$};
    \useasboundingbox (-\r-\m/2*\f,-\r-\m*3/4*\f) rectangle (\r+\m*\f+1,\r+1);
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the given animation reduced my internet quota by `1.366MB`.

Comment: @Marienplatz And yet (at the time of writing) it isn't the largest animated gif on this page.