# Tikz coordinate calculations inside foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, foreach, coordinates

As part of a drawing that will go with an explanation of diffraction, I want to draw the "outer rays" of a beam of light and draw several rays in between. An MWE of how I'm going about this is shown below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \draw[black,semithick] (-3,1) -- (0,1);
    \draw[black,semithick] (-3,-1) -- (0,-1);
    \def \n {10}
    \foreach \s in {1,...\n-1}
    {
        \draw[lightgray,semithick] ($(-3,1)!\s/\n!(-3,-1)$) -- ($(0,1)!\s/\n!(0,-1)$);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
\pgffor@stop \pgffor@@stop \expandafter \pgffor@dots@charcheck \pgffor@dotsvalue \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \pgffor@dots@stripcontext.
```

The `pgffor@dots` stuff makes me suspect the problem might lie in the range specification for `\s` but as far as I can tell there's nothing wrong with it. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: you forgot a comma in `1,...\n-1` but that arithmetic also won't work. Use     `\foreach \s in {1,...,\number\numexpr\n-1}`

Comment: D'oh. Such blindness...

Comment: Duplicate of: [How to use declared TikZ functions in \foreach condition?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110962)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel To be fair I don't think the questions are duplicates at all, even if the answer/underlying problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `,` in `{1,...\n-1}` which should be `{1,...,\n-1}` Note the `,` after `...`. Further I have defined `\n-1` as a macro and taken it outside the loop (this can be done with the facilities of `\foreach` too though).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \draw[black,semithick] (-3,1) -- (0,1);
    \draw[black,semithick] (-3,-1) -- (0,-1);
    \def \n {10}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{\n-1}
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\tmp}
    {
        \draw[lightgray,semithick] ($(-3,1)!\s/\n!(-3,-1)$) -- ($(0,1)!\s/\n!(0,-1)$);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I should have noticed that missing `,` though :P However, I would like some expansion on the `\n-1`. I assume it doesn't work because the `-1` is interpreted as a unit and not as part of an arithmetic expression. Can I do arithmetics in the range definition of a `foreach` loop?

Comment: @Wouter: percusse already told: `\number\numexpr\n-1`. I would go with `\pgfmathsetmacro` way as in my answer.

Comment: Ah yes, I see percusse edited their comment. Thanks again.

Comment: It might be appropriate to use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` (it doesn't matter in this example, though).