# foreach limit computed through an operation between pgfmathsetlengthmacros

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I'm still not too used to `\pgfmath...` commands and `calc` tikzlibrary operations.

Today I wanted to use an operation between two macros defined with `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` as a upper `foreach` limit. Something like

```
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\X{10mm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\Y{2mm}

\foreach \i in {0,...,\X/\Y}
```

or

```
\foreach \i in {0,...,{int(\X/\Y)}}
```

or

```
\foreach \i in {0,...,{int(scalar(\X/\Y))}}
```

Second and third solutions were written because the previous didn't work, but without really understanding where is the problem.

None of this three examples worked and finally I could solve it with an auxiliary macro

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XdivY}{\X/\Y}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\XdivY}
```

Could you explain me why my first tests didn't work? How can I write a correct operation between `\X` and `\Y` as a limit for `\foreach`?

In case you want some code for testing, here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\X{10mm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\Y{2mm}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XdivY}{\X/\Y}

\foreach \i in {0,...,\XdivY}
    \node at (\i,0) {\i};

% This doesn't work 
%\foreach \i in {0,...,{int(scalar(\X/\Y))}}
%   \node at (\i,0) {\i};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: foreach doesn't evaluate expressions in the iter list. You can use `\numexpr...\relax` though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some new macros of mine; some part of the code is not used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example

\ExplSyntaxOn
\providecommand\fpeval{\fp_eval:n}
\providecommand\dimtofp{\dim_to_fp:n}

\NewDocumentCommand{\nforeach}{ m +m }
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__manual_nforeach_type_tl
  \keys_set:nn { manual/nforeach }
   {
    type=integers,start = 1, step = 1, end = 0,
   }
  \keys_set:nn { manual/nforeach } { #1 }
  \__manual_nforeach_exec:n { #2 }
 }

\int_new:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int
\int_new:N \g__manual_fp_map_int
\tl_new:N \l__manual_nforeach_type_tl

\keys_define:nn { manual/nforeach }
 {
  type .choice:,
  type .value_required:n = true,
  type/integers .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_nforeach_type_tl { integers },
  type/fp       .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_nforeach_type_tl { fp },
  type/alph     .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_nforeach_type_tl { alph },
  type/Alph     .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_nforeach_type_tl { Alph },
  start .tl_set:N = \l__manual_nforeach_start_tl,
  step  .tl_set:N = \l__manual_nforeach_step_tl,
  end   .tl_set:N = \l__manual_nforeach_end_tl,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__manual_nforeach_exec:n
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int
  \str_case:Vn \l__manual_nforeach_type_tl
   {
    {integers}{\__manual_nforeach_exec_integers:n { #1 }}
    {fp}      {\__manual_nforeach_exec_fp:n { #1 }}
    {alph}    {\__manual_nforeach_exec_alph:Nn \int_to_alph:n { #1 }}
    {Alph}    {\__manual_nforeach_exec_alph:Nn \int_to_Alph:n { #1 }}
   }
  \int_gdecr:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__manual_nforeach_exec_integers:n
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn
   { \l__manual_nforeach_start_tl }
   { \l__manual_nforeach_step_tl }
   { \l__manual_nforeach_end_tl }
   { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__manual_nforeach_exec_alph:Nn
 {
  \cs_set:cn { __manual_nforeach_alph_ \int_use:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int :n } { #2 }
  \cs_generate_variant:cn
   { __manual_nforeach_alph_ \int_use:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int :n }
   { f }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn
   { \int_from_alph:f { \l__manual_nforeach_start_tl } }
   { \l__manual_nforeach_step_tl }
   { \int_from_alph:f { \l__manual_nforeach_end_tl } }
   {
    \use:c { __manual_nforeach_alph_ \int_use:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int :f }
     { #1 { ##1 } }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_generate_variant:Nn { c }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_alph:n { f }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__manual_nforeach_exec_fp:n
 {
  \manual_fp_step_inline:nnnn
   { \l__manual_nforeach_start_tl }
   { \l__manual_nforeach_step_tl }
   { \l__manual_nforeach_end_tl }
   { #1 }
 }

% a replacement for \fp_step_inline:nnnn
\seq_new:N \l__manual_fp_step_seq
\fp_new:N \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp

\cs_new_protected:Nn \manual_fp_step_inline:nnnn
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g__manual_fp_map_int
  \seq_clear_new:c { l__manual_fp_step_ \int_use:N \g__manual_fp_map_int _seq }
  \fp_compare:nTF { #2 < \c_zero_fp }
   {
    \__manual_fp_step_make_neg:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \__manual_fp_step_make_pos:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
  \seq_map_inline:cn { l__manual_fp_step_ \int_use:N \g__manual_fp_map_int _seq } { #4 }
  \int_gdecr:N \g__manual_fp_map_int
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__manual_fp_step_make_neg:nnn
 {
  \fp_set:Nn \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp { #1 }
  \fp_do_while:nn { \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp >= #3 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:cx { l__manual_fp_step_ \int_use:N \g__manual_fp_map_int _seq }
     { \fp_eval:n { \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp } }
    \fp_add:Nn \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp { #2 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__manual_fp_step_make_pos:nnn
 {
  \fp_set:Nn \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp { #1 }
  \fp_do_while:nn { \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp <= #3 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:cx { l__manual_fp_step_ \int_use:N \g__manual_fp_map_int _seq }
     { \fp_eval:n { \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp } }
    \fp_add:Nn \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp { #2 }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\lforeach}{ s O{} m +m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \manual_lforeach:non { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \manual_lforeach:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \manual_lforeach:nnn
 {
  \keys_set:nn { manual/lforeach } { single }
  \keys_set:nn { manual/lforeach } { #1 }
  \clist_set:Nn \l__manual_lforeach_list_clist { #2 }
  \int_gincr:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int
  \__manual_lforeach_define:n { #3 }
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__manual_lforeach_list_clist
   {
    \use:c { __manual_lforeach_ \int_use:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int _action:w } ##1 \q_stop
   }
  \int_gdecr:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \manual_lforeach:nnn { no }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__manual_lforeach_define:n
 {
  \exp_last_unbraced:NcV
   \cs_set:Npn
   { __manual_lforeach_ \int_use:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int _action:w }
   \l__manual_lforeach_format_tl
   \q_stop
   {#1}
 }

\keys_define:nn { manual/lforeach }
 {
  format .tl_set:N = \l__manual_lforeach_format_tl,
  single .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_lforeach_format_tl { ##1 },
  double .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_lforeach_format_tl { ##1/##2 },
  triple .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_lforeach_format_tl { ##1/##2/##3 },
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\ignasiX}{30mm}
\newcommand{\ignasiY}{6mm}
\newcommand{\ignasiA}{45pt}
\newcommand{\ignasiB}{17pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\nforeach{
  start=0,
  end=\fpeval{trunc(\dimtofp{\ignasiX}/\dimtofp{\ignasiY})},
  step=1,
}{
  \node at (#1,0) {#1};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\nforeach{
  type=fp,
  start=0,
  end=\fpeval{trunc(\dimtofp{\ignasiA}/\dimtofp{\ignasiB})},
  step=0.3,
}{
  \node at (#1,#1) {#1};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can do it also with `\foreach`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\X{10mm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\Y{2mm}

\foreach \i in {0,...,\numexpr\dimexpr\X/\dimexpr\Y\relax}
    \node at (\i,0) {\i};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should buy an abacus for the sake of convenience :-).

Comment: I won't be able to remember all these macros every time I want to use a foreach, so I'll try to remember your second solution and percusse's comment. :-)

Comment: @Ignasi Maybe they'll become a package in the future; they'll be the topic of my talk at the next GuITmeeting.

Answer (score 1):

As [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329606/foreach-limit-computed-through-an-operation-between-pgfmathsetlengthmacros#comment807535_329606) said, the `\foreach` macro doesn't evaluate the elements of a list – at least not by default.

However, the [`/pgf/foreach/parse` key](https://tikz.dev/pgffor#pgf/foreach/parse) activates the parsing for the last element in the list. For some reason its default value is `false` and not `true` as with other boolean keys, so you'd need `parse=true` or a quick fix like

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/foreach/parse/.default=true}
```

It should be noted that you can't use more complex elements (but they're rarely are with `...`) and the last element needs to be parseable by `\pgfmathparse`, of course.

Though, for simple calculations `\numexpr` might still be the best tool since it's probably faster than using the full PGFMath parser.

For more complex lists, I'd suggest taking a look at `use int` and `use float` from [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110996/16595).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% for some reason, parse doesn't
% default to parse=true, fix it:
\pgfkeys{/pgf/foreach/parse/.default=true}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\X{10mm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\Y{2mm}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\XdivY}{\X/\Y}

\foreach \i in {0,...,\XdivY}
    \node at (\i,0) {\i};

\foreach \i[parse] in {0,...,\X/\Y}
  \node at (\i,-1) {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code