# Problem when applying foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, dimensions

I'm trying to find the minimum *x* coordinate in a set of Ti*k*Z coordinates.

Consider this code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newdimen\x
\newdimen\xmin
\xmin=10000pt
\newdimen\y
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
\node (1) {182};
\node[below=of 1] (2) {183731468};
\node[below=of 2] (3) {74632};
\path (1.west); \pgfgetlastxy{\x}{\y}
\ifdim\x<\xmin \xmin=\x \fi
\fill[red] (\xmin,\y) circle (1pt);
\path (2.west); \pgfgetlastxy{\x}{\y}
\ifdim\x<\xmin \xmin=\x \fi
\fill[red] (\xmin,\y) circle (1pt);
\path (3.west); \pgfgetlastxy{\x}{\y}
\ifdim\x<\xmin \xmin=\x \fi
\fill[red] (\xmin,\y) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and this code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newdimen\x
\newdimen\xmin
\xmin=10000pt
\newdimen\y
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
\node (1) {182};
\node[below=of 1] (2) {183731468};
\node[below=of 2] (3) {74632};
\foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
    \path (\i.west); \pgfgetlastxy{\x}{\y}
    \ifdim\x<\xmin \xmin=\x \fi
    \fill[red] (\xmin,\y) circle (1pt);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

These are the outputs of the first code (left) and the second code (right) side by side:

[image] [image]

Look at the dot at the bottom. The first code gives the intended output, but the second doesn't.

Why? And how to modify the `\foreach` loop in the second code so that it gives the same output as the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `\foreach` variant, you are in a group when setting the dimension, so the "outside" value won't change. So you need to make the dimension global (or [smuggle it out of the group](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470979/121799)). Here I made it global by just adding `\global` before `\xmin=\x`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newdimen\x
\newdimen\xmin
\xmin=10000pt
\newdimen\y
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
\node (1) {182};
\node[below=of 1] (2) {183731468};
\node[below=of 2] (3) {74632};
\foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
    \path (\i.west); \pgfgetlastxy{\x}{\y}
    \ifdim\x<\xmin \global\xmin=\x \fi
    \fill[red] (\xmin,\y) circle (1pt);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: Of course, there are loops which do not introduce groups. The arguably simplest of those is the built-in `\loop`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newdimen\x
\newdimen\xmin
\xmin=10000pt
\newdimen\y
\newcounter{loopi}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
\node (1) {182};
\node[below=of 1] (2) {183731468};
\node[below=of 2] (3) {74632};
\setcounter{loopi}{0}
\loop
\stepcounter{loopi}
    \path (\number\value{loopi}.west); \pgfgetlastxy{\x}{\y}
    \ifdim\x<\xmin \xmin=\x \fi
    \fill[red] (\xmin,\y) circle (1pt);
\ifnum\number\value{loopi}<3\repeat
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @JouleV You only change the local but not the outside value. (This is also the reason why `\draw[blue] ...` renders only the `...` but not every other path blue. Likewise, if you say `\tikz[blue]{....}` everything in the `tikzpicture` will be blue, but not outside, and so on.) In TeX all macros are local unless you explicitly make them global.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a different loop that doesn't do grouping. Instead of `\i` you use simply `#1`.

```latex
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\nforeach}{mmm}
 {
  \cs_set:Nn \joulev_nforeach:n { #3 }
  \int_step_function:nnN { #1 } { #2 } \joulev_nforeach:n
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newdimen\x
\newdimen\xmin
\newdimen\y

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
\xmin=10000pt
\node (1) {182};
\node[below=of 1] (2) {183731468};
\node[below=of 2] (3) {74632};
\nforeach{1}{3}{
  \path (#1.west); \pgfgetlastxy{\x}{\y}
  \ifdim\x<\xmin \xmin=\x \fi
  \fill[red] (\xmin,\y) circle (1pt);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I will have to start learning `expl3` syntax soon. What does those commands inside `\ExplSyntax` mean?

Comment: @JouleV The first line sets a temporary function according to the code in the third argument; the second line does a loop from the starting point (first argument) to the final point (second argument). No fancy syntax like `\foreach`, but for most cases it's sufficient. You find a more elaborate implementation at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329628/4427