# Problem with drawing thick line

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

With the solution posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140782/drawing-a-neural-network-architecture), I only changed a little (at line 17, I added `[thick, ->]` after `\draw`):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   cnode/.style={draw=black,fill=#1,minimum width=3mm,circle},
]
    \node[cnode=red,label=0:$\Sigma$] (s) at (6,-3) {};
    \node at (0,-4) {$\vdots$};
    \node at (3,-4) {$\vdots$};
    \foreach \x in {1,...,4}
    {   \pgfmathparse{\x<4 ? \x : "n"}
        \node[cnode=blue,label=180:$x_{\pgfmathresult}$] (x-\x) at (0,{-\x-div(\x,4)}) {};
        \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$\varphi_{\pgfmathresult}$] (p-\x) at (3,{-\x-div(\x,4)}) {};

        %%%%%%%%Changed this line   
        \draw[thick, ->] (p-\x) -- node[above,sloped,pos=0.3] {$\omega_{\pgfmathresult}$} (s);
    }
    \foreach \x in {1,...,4}
    {   \foreach \y in {1,...,4}
        {   \draw (x-\x) -- (p-\y);
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Note that the texts with `\omega` have been changed to `0.8`. Why is this happening and how to fix that?

Comment: If you add the `thick` option at the end of the path, i.e. `\draw[->] … node {\pgfmathresult} … [thick];`, the `\pgfmathresult` macro won’t get overwritten. But it is better to have a dedicated macro anyway. Here you can also use `\foreach \x[evaluate={\mytemp=\x<4?int(\x):"n"}] in {1,...,4}`. By the way, you can also use `\pgfmathprint{\x<4?int(\x):"n"}` directly in the node (but that evaluates `\x<4` three times, of course).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel `\pgfmathprint{\x<4?int(\x):"n"}` worked fine. But can you give a MWE for `\foreach \x[evaluate={\mytemp=\x<4?int(\x):"n"}]` ?

Answer (score 7):

Think of `\pgfmathresult` as the `\temp` macro that everytime a math operation is done it gets overwritten. `thick` makes the line width 0.8pt and it is used somewhere in the bowels as a math operation. So, `\pgfmathresult` gets overwritten. Instead if you make it a fixed macro to hold the value it works as expected

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   cnode/.style={draw=black,fill=#1,minimum width=3mm,circle},
]
    \node[cnode=red,label=0:$\Sigma$] (s) at (6,-3) {};
    \node at (0,-4) {$\vdots$};
    \node at (3,-4) {$\vdots$};
    \foreach \x in {1,...,4}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro\mytemp{\x<4 ? int(\x) : "n"}
        \node[cnode=blue,label=180:$x_{\mytemp}$] (x-\x) at (0,{-\x-div(\x,4)}) {};
        \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$\varphi_{\mytemp}$] (p-\x) at (3,{-\x-div(\x,4)}) {};
        \draw[thick, ->] (p-\x) -- node[above,sloped,pos=0.3] {$\omega_{\mytemp}$} (s);
    }
    \foreach \x in {1,...,4}
    {   \foreach \y in {1,...,4}
        {   \draw (x-\x) -- (p-\y);
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But, now I'm getting error: `Missing number, treated as zero }`. After searching, I found [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43226/missing-number-error-using-pgfmathsetmacro-with-the-ifthenelse-operator)!

Comment: @pushpen.paul Ah yes this is fixed in the CVS version. Sorry I forgot that I'm using the beta version of the new release

Comment: @pushpen.paul I usually just define `\newcommand*\pgfMathsetmacro[2]{\pgfmathparse{#2}\let#1\pgfmathresult}` that works like `\pgfmathsetmacro` but can work with every output in `\pgfmathresult`.